# $\inf_{x \in D} |x-a|^p \le \inf_{x \in D} |x-a|^{p-1} \inf_{x \in D} |x-a|$ for $p>1$.

Tags: analysis, inequality

I am wondering if the following inequality is true is 
\begin{align}
\inf_{x \in D} |x-a|^p \le \inf_{x \in D} |x-a|^{p-1}  \inf_{x \in D} |x-a|
\end{align}
for any $p \ge 1$. Observe, $a$ might not be in $D$.

So, for $p=1$ this is trivial. Also, if $a\in D$ this is also trivial.

What about other cases $p>1$ and $a\notin D$.

I tried a few examples and couldn't find a counter example.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there is an equality, and it does not matter whether $a\in D$ or not. Since the functions $z^{p}$ and $z^{p-1}$ are non-decreasing for $z\ge 0$, for any non-negative function $f$
$$
\inf_{x \in D} f(x)^p =    \left(\inf_{x \in D} f(x)\right)^p =  \left(\inf_{x \in D} f(x)\right)^{p-1} \inf_{x \in D} f(x)
= \inf_{x \in D} f(x)^{p-1}\inf_{x \in D} f(x);
$$
you can put $f(x) = |x-a|$ to get an answer to the original question.